# mod_rewrite issues with RewriteRule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can this rule be modified:

`RewriteRule ^/it(.*)$ /information-technology$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]`

to handle all scenarios below?  (As-is above does not work for those marked **ERROR**)

- `/it`
- `/IT`
- `/it/`
- `/IT/` **(ERROR - does not redirect)**

--

- `/it/team/` redirects to `/information-technology/team/`
- `/it/team` **(ERROR - does not redirect)**
- `/IT/team`  redirects to `/information-technology/`  **(ERROR)**
- `/IT/team`/  redirects to `/information-technology/`  **(ERROR)**

--

- `/italics`  redirects to `/information-technology/alics` **(ERROR)**

--

Thank you for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?it(/.*)?$ /information-technology$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

- Make sure this is top most rule in your site root .htaccess
- Make sure to test it in a new browser

Comment: thank you!!  we are closer..... but these 3 still do NOT resolved:   /IT/team redirects to /information-technology/ (ERROR)
/IT/team/ redirects to /information-technology/ (ERROR)
--

/italics redirects to /information-technology/alics (ERROR)

Comment: Update:  Sorry, only the last issue remains... with /italics.  I do not want it to redirect to /information-technology/.

Comment: Above rule will not redirect `/italics` or `/italy`. That is due to old browser cache or some other rule

Comment: browser cache was the culprit!  Thank you for the speedy help! @anubhava